# Accord dans "s'il y a [nom féminin] de [participe passé]'

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Dans la phrase *s'il y a une maison de [PP de déclarer]*, doit-on écrire écrire *déclaré* ou *déclarée* ?

Comment: Accord: **Une** de perdu**e**, **dix** de retrouv**ées**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dans cette phrase, on utiliserait plutôt le féminin :

*s'il y a une maison de déclarée*

Mais cette tournure est vieillotte ou à la rigueur familière. On devrait plutôt écrire :

*si une maison est déclarée*